# clojure - avoid extra whitespace when combining string and variable

Tags: string, clojure, println, removing-whitespace

I'm writing a program that uses printl-str to return commands of an assembly language. I need to use variables in my code and I'm having this issue where the function will return extra whitespace where I don't want it:

```
(defn pushConstant [constant]
   (println-str "@" constant "\r\nD=A\r\n@SP\r\nA=M\r\nM=D\r\n@SP\r\nM=M+1"))
```

Where instead of having, assuming that constant = 17

```
@17
D=A
@SP
A=M
M=D
@SP
M=M+1
```

I'm having:

```
@ 17
D=A
@SP
A=M
M=D
@SP
M=M+1
```

Which is problematic for my assembly code. I have this issue in so many cases like this. I'll be glad to hear advice on how to avoid this extra whitespace between the String and the variable.

Comment: I'd be generating and passing around lists or sequences of assembly instructions, and not dealing with strings until the last possible time. Much easier to deal with higher-level data structures rather than string buffers that need to be parsed to have semantic meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, I'd implement that to look more like the following:

```
(defn pushConstant [constant]
  (->> [(str "@" constant)
        "D=A"
        "@SP"
        "A=M"
        "M=D"
        "@SP"
        "M=M+1"]
       (interpose "\r\n")
       (apply str)))
```

That way you don't have one big ugly format string, but break down your operations into small, readable pieces.

That said, the piece that makes a difference for you here is `(str "@" constant)`, combining your `@` with the argument with no added whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Create the string using `str` which only concatenates (println interleaves spaces):

```
(defn pushConstant [constant]
   (println-str (str "@" constant "\r\nD=A\r\n@SP\r\nA=M\r\nM=D\r\n@SP\r\nM=M+1")))
```